# How to use webshim in EmberJS?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, webshim

I like to use [webshim](https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) in [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) for a better user experience when input type time is not supported by browser (like current versions of Firefox, Internet Explorer). But there seems to be an issue concerning bindings. While model gets updated when a value is selected by user, the input field is not updated when model changes.

It seems like webshim requires `JQuery().val()` to be used to change a value but Ember does not use this method. Also I can not find any information in webshims documentation about how to trigger an update after value changes.

This seems to be a problem not only in EmberJS but also in other frameworks. It was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292189/programmatically-updating-a-webshim-date) for [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). For Knockout the solution was to extend normal value binding and use `JQuery().val()`. But I have absolutely no idea how to do this in Ember.js or if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the solution. I could trigger `change` in next Ember run loop.

```
Ember.run.next(this, function(){
  Ember.$('input[type="time"]').trigger('change');
});
```